# NRE only while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

We recently ran across a weird issue in our product-code. When debugging we got a `NullReferenceException` where we didn't expect any.

So we narrowed it down to the following MCVE:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace VSReproCase
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReproCase reproCase = new ReproCase { ExecuteCheck = args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "true" };
            reproCase.CheckLaufendeNummer();
        }
    }

    class TestObject
    {
        public TestObject(string currentNumber)
        {
            CurrentNumber = currentNumber;
        }
        public string CurrentNumber { get; set; }
    }

    class ReproCase
    {
        public bool ExecuteCheck { get; set; }

        public bool CheckLaufendeNummer()
        {
            bool success = true;
            if (ExecuteCheck)
            {
                string tempCurrentNumberPrefix = "TestObject";
                List<TestObject> objectList = new List<TestObject>
                {
                    new TestObject("TestObject1"), new TestObject("TestObject2"),
                    new TestObject("TestObject3"), new TestObject("TestObject4"),
                };
                foreach (var testObject in objectList.OfType<TestObject>().Where(x => x.CurrentNumber != null && x.CurrentNumber.StartsWith(tempCurrentNumberPrefix)))
                {
                    success = false;
                }
            }

            return success;
        }
    }
}
```

which runs if `ExecuteCheck` returns `true` and when it is `false`. However it does *not*  work when it is `false` and we step over `if(Execute)` in order to skip this check. The weird thing is that the exception is being thrown on the string-assignment, which is obvious non-sense but even after re-compiling this stays the same.

[image]

I checked it with VS2017 and VS 2010 in DEBUG-build.

Of course we can simply avoid this by declaring `tempCurrentNumberPrefix` before the check. However I don't understand why this is necessary.

EDIT: seems that the value of `Execute` is meaningless, also if it is `true` and we step over the check we get the exact same behaviour.

Comment: I think that the error is somewhere else in the code and VS is only displaying the wrong information. I would try to clean the project and rebuild it. Also you could try to create the variable first and then assign the value. Maybe VS likes this more xD

Comment: I did re-build the project.

Comment: That little `.StartsWith()` you've got there forces the access to `tempCurrentNumberPrefix` to be hoisted into a closure. My guess is that the debugger gets confused about exactly what statements to skip when you skip over the check, and it merrily skips over the code that's supposed to `newobj` this closure, causing the NRE. Do you only get this when debugging and manually changing the location of the next instruction, or is it an actual problem in production code?

Comment: Have you tried to debug from VS without any addons and plugins (like ReSharper and so on)? And what about other debugers? Does your code throws when running under WinDbg?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I also assumed something like the closure here. I get this only on debugging when manually setting the current location.

Comment: @AleksAndreev Don´t have any other debugger to test, unfortunately. Disabling R# didn´t change anything.

Comment: Then depending on your POV, it's either not worth worrying about or it warrants posting a [bug report](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio) to see if this can be improved in the debugger. Manually changing the next location is not an easy thing to do consistently and without surprises when compiler magic has transformed the code in creative ways. From the debugger's POV, it may have given you "exactly what you asked for", not realizing that the question had changed between the C# and the IL.

Comment: A reasonable workaround is to explicitly set `ExecuteCheck` to a new value before and/or after the check instead of messing with the instruction pointer. (You may need to assign it to a temporary if it's a nontrivial property.) That has a much better chance of going over well (though it's still no guarantee).